# React Typescript passing props and data type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm still pretty new into the world of TypeScript and I have a couple of questions. I have a few errors in my code, and I'm not rlly sure how to pass the props and choose the right type. I would appreciate a bit of help on that one.

Do you have maybe a good source where I can find all the necessary React info in one place just for the start?

tl;dr

1. What will be the { data } type? How to define it?
2. How to pass the functions as props to the Results.tsx file? How define result, results and openPopup in this function?
3. Did I miss something else?

**App.tsx**

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import Search from './components/Search'
import Results from './components/Results'
import Popup from './components/Popup'


export type selected = {
    Title?: string,
    Year?:number
}

type values = {
s: string,
results: string[],
selected: selected,
}

interface popup {
    id: string
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<values>({
    s: "",
    results: [],
    selected: {}
  });


  const apiurl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=dfe6d885";

  const search = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      axios(apiurl + "&s=" + state.s).then(({ data }) => {
        let results = data.Search;

        setState(prevState => {
          return { ...prevState, results: results }
        })
      });
    }
  }
  
  const handleInput = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let s = e.target.value;

    setState(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, s: s }
    });
  }

  const openPopup = (id : string) => {
    axios(apiurl + "&i=" + id).then(({ data }) => {
      let result = data;

      console.log(result);

      setState(prevState => {
        return { ...prevState, selected: result }
      });
    });
  }

  const closePopup = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, selected: {} }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>Movie Database</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <Search handleInput={handleInput} search={search} />

        <Results results={state.results} openPopup={openPopup} />

        {(typeof state.selected.Title != "undefined") ? <Popup selected={state.selected} closePopup={closePopup} /> : false}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

**Results.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'

import Result from './Result'

function Results ({ results, openPopup }) {
    return (
        <section className="results">
            {results.map(result => (
                <Result key={result.imdbID} result={result} openPopup={openPopup} />
            ))}
        </section>
    )
}

export default Results
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Prop Types

You can defined the props that you pass to a function component inline

```
function Results ({ results, openPopup }: { results: MyResult[], openPopup: () => void }) {
```

But it's more common to define a separate `interface` for the props

```
interface Props {
    results: MyResult[];
    openPopup: () => void;
}
```

Which you can use to define the props directly

```
function Results ({ results, openPopup }: Props) {
```

Or through `React.FC`

```
const Results: React.FC<Props> = ({ results, openPopup }) => {
```

#### Data Type

To define the type for `data` you need to create an `interface` that has all of the properties in the API response that you want to use.  Then when you call `axios`, you use the generic type of the `axios` function to tell it what the fetched data should look like.

For whatever reason, `axios()` doesn't seem to take a generic, but `axios.get()` does.

```
axios.get<MyApiResponse>(apiurl + "&s=" + state.s).then(({ data }) => {
```

Now the `data` variable automatically has the `MyApiResponse` type.

Comment: This method does not provide the React-provided properties like `children`.

Comment: @JoséRamírez thanks for pointing this out.  `React.FC` used to include `children?: ReactNode` but it does not anymore as React version 18.